# Track ID of user clicking URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, url-rewriting, event-handling, user-tracking

My team is developing a chatbot application that at one points gives the user a URL, and we need to keep track of who clicks on the link. All the possible URLs (approximately 20) point to pages on the same domain, one in which we have no influence on (e.g. `https://www.other-domain.com/page01`). Moreover, the chatbot application is deployed via WhatsApp, which prevents us from using solutions that would otherwise work when the application is deployed on our client's website (e.g. using Javascript to track click events, using Google Analytics, etc.).

Given these restrictions, we think the best approach would be to produce a per-user URL (think of a URL shortener) that, when clicked, registers which user clicked on it, and then redirects the user to the corresponding page. For example, user `alice` would click on `https://shorter.url/page01?user=alice`, and then be redirected to `https://www.other-domain.com/page01`. However, we are not sure how to implement something like this.

Any advice on how to implement this solution, or other solution that we haven't thought of, would be greatly appreciated. This strikes me as a problem that is not so niche, and yet we haven't found any online tools (paid or otherwise) to solve it. The chatbot application is developed using AWS, so AWS-based solutions are ideal (but not required).